# Split string on a Regex

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I have the following strings

1. mo474334pt1572
2. at1088ma15
3. ma15pt1983
4. ca1

I want to obtain

```
a) string[] result = new[] {"mo474334", "pt1572"};
a) string[] result = new[] {"at1088", "ma15"};
a) string[] result = new[] {"ma15", "pt1983"};
c) string[] result = new[] {"ca1"};
```

I have been trying the following approaches with little success

```
string[] result = Regex.Split(str, @"\[A-Za-z]{2}[0-9]*");

string[] result = Regex.Split(str, @"\[A-Za-z]{2}[0-9]*\[A-Za-z]{2}[0-9]*");
```

and

```
string[] result = Regex.Matches(str, @"^[A-Za-z]{2}[0-9]*").Cast<Match>().Select(m => m.Value).ToArray();
```

Can anyone see where I am going wrong, Is this achieveable ? Or should I use another approach

Comment: You could split on boundary digit/letter: `(?<=\d)(?=[a-z]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of split, you could match 2 times a char a-zA-Z and 1 or more digits 0-9

```
[A-Za-z]{2}[0-9]+
```

[Regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5bA-Za-z%5d%7b2%7d%5b0-9%5d%2b&i=mo474334pt1572%0d%0aat1088ma15%0d%0ama15pt1983%0d%0aca1) | [C# demo](https://ideone.com/KZtNLs)

---

If you want to use split, one way could be using a positive lookahead

```
\B(?=[A-Za-z]{2}[0-9])
```

- `\B` Assert a position where a wordboundary does not match
- `(?=` Positive lookahead, assert what is on the right is

  - `[A-Za-z]{2}[0-9]` match 2 times a char a-zA-Z
- `)` Close lookahead

[Regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5cB%28%3f%3d%5bA-Za-z%5d%7b2%7d%5b0-9%5d%29&i=mo474334pt1572%0d%0aat1088ma15%0d%0ama15pt1983%0d%0aca1&r=) | [C# demo](https://ideone.com/2NhXZ0)

[image]